# Prototyping with ATMEGA328P-PU (DIP-28) for ATMEGA328P-AU (TQFP-32)

Tags: atmega328p

My schematic will use internal oscillator, but will not require precise timing. It will be produced using surface-mounted ATMEGA328P-AU (in TQFP-32 package). However this is not convenient for prototyping, so I'd like to prototype using ATMEGA328P-PU (in DIP-28 packaging). Will this work in this scenario?

Comment: Why should it not work? What kind of issue do you expect?

Comment: I've never done this before this way, so just asking. So something like "it will work [and I have done that]" or "it will not work because..." would be perfect answers/

Comment: Ok so the ATMEGA328P-AU behaves exact the some way the ATMEGA328P-PU does, because it's the same controller, just another package. The only thing that should be taken into consideration is, if all pins you need are connected in the DIP package.

Comment: Why do you believe that prototyping in TQFP is less convenient than in DIP-28? You will eventually need to make it in TQFP footprint, with proper pin placement. If your goal is to provide early platform for software development, it is better to do this in configuration as close as the final product as possible. All you need is to place few debug headers around the TQFP.

Comment: Because I prototype on a breadboard. I can solder TQFP on a DIP adapter, but it will have pins on each side, which will not work with a breadboard as all horizontal pins would be shortened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transferred prototype from Arduino UNO to custom PCB with TQFP-32 without problems. I used Eagle, where I had the scema to create that PCB from scrach, my only problem was, that I use too narrow paths, so while soldering I destroid two pads in vias. Solved it with a piece of copper wire manually riveted in those vias and used as base for soldering, but it does not had anything with CPU. Also created PCB for USB version and worked as expected. I do not see any problems in your way. (If you can create PCB later with different layout ot wires).

You can use/make adapters for breadboards with pins just on two sides, like in Arduino Mini Pro (which is TQFP too) or this one http://www.dx.com/p/elecfreaks-aplomb-boards-tqfp44-32-adapter-board-flower12-for-arduino-green-392511